# Why my vuejs wallpaper calculator doesn't work?

Tags: vue.js

After changing the numbers, for example, in the first or seconde input, the result is false. Only changing the values in  gives me the right results.

If I put 40 in the first input and 3 in the seconde one and others I leave the same, the result should be 26.

Please, could you help me.

```
<body>
<div id="app">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent>
    <span>Довжина стіни, м:</span><br>
    <input class="length" type="text" name="length" v-model.text.trim="wall_length"><br>
    <span>Висота стіни, м:</span><br>
    <input class="heigth" type="text" name="heigth" v-model.text.trim="wall_height"><br>
    <hr>
    <span>Ширина рулона, м:</span><br>
    <select v-model="selected">
        <option  v-for="key in weight" :value="key">{{key}}</option>
    </select><br>
    <span>Довжина рулона, м:</span><br>
    <input class="length_roll" type="text" name="length_roll" v-model.text.trim="length" maxlength="5"><br>
    <span>Повтор малюнка (рапорт), см:</span><br>
    <input class="rapport" type="text" name="rapport" v-model.text.trim="rapport"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Порахувати" v-on:click="calc">
    </form>
    <span>{{result}} рулонів шпалер</span>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el : "#app",
        data: {
            title: "Калькулятор шпалер",
            wall_length: 20,
            wall_height: 2.75,
            weight: [0.53, 1.05],
            rapport: 0,
            length: 10.05,
            selected: 0.53,
            polotno_for_room: 0,
            polotno_rulon: 0,
            result: 0
        },
        methods: {
            calc: function () {
        this.polotno_for_room = (this.wall_length + this.wall_height)/ this.selected;
        this.polotno_rulon = this.length /(this.wall_height + 0.10);
        this.result = Math.ceil(this.polotno_for_room/this.polotno_rulon);
        console.log((this.wall_length + this.wall_height)/ this.selected);
        console.log(this.polotno_rulon = this.length /(this.wall_height + 0.10));
        console.log(Math.ceil(this.polotno_for_room/this.polotno_rulon));

    }
        }

        });


</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are using an input with `type="text"`. The result of this is a string. When you start your application, the state of your component is initialised to what you set as data, which makes `wall_length` and `wall_height` numbers. The moment you change one of the inputs, the type of these variables changes to a `string.

Due to how javascript works, it will now do string concatenation instead of adding two numbers. It will then convert it back to a number for dividing by whatever `this.selected` is. The result is that instead of doing dividing 40 + 3 = 43 by `this.selected`, you are dividing "40" + 3 = 403 by `this.selected`. Notice the `typeof` checks I added behind the inputs to showcase this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    title: "Калькулятор шпалер",
    wall_length: 40,
    wall_height: 3,
    weight: [0.53, 1.05],
    rapport: 0,
    length: 10.05,
    selected: 0.53,
    polotno_for_room: 0,
    polotno_rulon: 0,
    result: 0
  },
  methods: {
    calc: function() {
      this.polotno_for_room = (this.wall_length + this.wall_height) / this.selected;
      this.polotno_rulon = this.length / (this.wall_height + 0.10);
      this.result = Math.ceil(this.polotno_for_room / this.polotno_rulon);
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent>
    <span>Довжина стіни, м:</span><br>
    <input class="length" type="text" name="length" v-model.text.trim="wall_length"> {{ typeof wall_length }}<br>
    <span>Висота стіни, м:</span><br>
    <input class="heigth" type="text" name="heigth" v-model.text.trim="wall_height"> {{ typeof wall_height }}<br>
    <hr>
    <span>Ширина рулона, м:</span><br>
    <select v-model="selected">
      <option v-for="key in weight" :value="key">{{key}}</option>
    </select><br>
    <span>Довжина рулона, м:</span><br>
    <input class="length_roll" type="text" name="length_roll" v-model.text.trim="length" maxlength="5"><br>
    <span>Повтор малюнка (рапорт), см:</span><br>
    <input class="rapport" type="text" name="rapport" v-model.text.trim="rapport"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Порахувати" v-on:click="calc">
  </form>
  <span>{{result}} рулонів шпалер</span>

</div>
```

One of your options is to use `parseFloat(..)` liberally. It will make sure you are using only numbers in your calculation.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    title: "Калькулятор шпалер",
    wall_length: 40,
    wall_height: 3,
    weight: [0.53, 1.05],
    rapport: 0,
    length: 10.05,
    selected: 0.53,
    polotno_for_room: 0,
    polotno_rulon: 0,
    result: 0
  },
  methods: {
    calc: function() {
      this.polotno_for_room = (parseFloat(this.wall_length) + parseFloat(this.wall_height)) / parseFloat(this.selected);
      this.polotno_rulon = parseFloat(this.length) / (parseFloat(this.wall_height) + 0.10);
      this.result = Math.ceil(parseFloat(this.polotno_for_room) / parseFloat(this.polotno_rulon));
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent>
    <span>Довжина стіни, м:</span><br>
    <input class="length" type="text" name="length" v-model.text.trim="wall_length"><br>
    <span>Висота стіни, м:</span><br>
    <input class="heigth" type="text" name="heigth" v-model.text.trim="wall_height"><br>
    <hr>
    <span>Ширина рулона, м:</span><br>
    <select v-model="selected">
      <option v-for="key in weight" :value="key">{{key}}</option>
    </select><br>
    <span>Довжина рулона, м:</span><br>
    <input class="length_roll" type="text" name="length_roll" v-model.text.trim="length" maxlength="5"><br>
    <span>Повтор малюнка (рапорт), см:</span><br>
    <input class="rapport" type="text" name="rapport" v-model.text.trim="rapport"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Порахувати" v-on:click="calc">
  </form>
  <span>{{result}} рулонів шпалер</span>

</div>
```